# add most viewed post by google analytic in loop

Tags: loop, google-analytics

I'm trying to find a solution to display the 5 post most viewed ( from google analytics) in my loop.

The only way I find at the moment is to use this plugin 'Google Analytics Top Content Widget
'

However, I don't wan't to use that and I'll wish to be able to add in my loop because I have a really specific layout for that, than this plugin can not do  .. .

ANy help will be amazing,

thank you guys !

Comment: IIRC, Google Analytics has an API. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Yoast's Analytics plugin, this wouldn't be super hard. However, it will require some coding knowledge. I won't spell everything out for you, but I will point you in the right direction. Without Yoast, you'll have to review [Lots of Documentation](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-analytics-api-v3-php-fetching-data/)

1. **Load Yoast GA Files/Classes and Analytics ID from Yoast (or use Google Client API itself)**
2. **Request Most Viewed Pages from Analytics and get post ids**
3. **Get Posts and Loop**

I've created an example here. Feel free to throw it in a function and try it as-is, though it is untested and may not work properly. This has a refresh-rate option (in minutes) and an option to hide your home page (which is usually the most viewed page, after all)

I stole a lot from the GA Top Content plugin.

```
function jr_get_ga_top_posts() {
    $expires = 5; // minutes
    $showhome = false; // if you want to hide the homepage, set true

    if ( false === ( $post_ids = get_transient('jr_ga_top_posts') ) ) {

        // check for Yoast and include files
        if ( ! class_exists( 'Yoast_Google_Analytics' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            $path = dirname( GAWP_FILE );
            $files_to_include = array(
                'Yoast_Google_CacheParser'      => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/io/Google_CacheParser.php',
                'Yoast_Google_Utils'            => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/service/Google_Utils.php',
                'Yoast_Google_HttpRequest'      => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/io/Google_HttpRequest.php',
                'Yoast_Google_IO'               => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/io/Google_IO.php',
                'Yoast_Google_WPIO'             => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/io/Google_WPIO.php',
                'Yoast_Google_Auth'             => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/auth/Google_Auth.php',
                'Yoast_Google_OAuth2'           => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/auth/Google_OAuth2.php',
                'Yoast_Google_Cache'            => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/cache/Google_Cache.php',
                'Yoast_Google_WPCache'          => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/cache/Google_WPCache.php',
                'Yoast_Google_Client'           => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/google/Google_Client.php',
                'Yoast_Google_Analytics_Client' => '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/googleanalytics/class-google-analytics-client.php',
            );

            if ( version_compare( GAWP_VERSION, '5.4.3' ) >= 0 ) {
                unset( $files_to_include['Yoast_Google_Analytics_Client'] );
                $files_to_include['Yoast_Api_Google_Client'] = '/vendor/yoast/api-libs/class-api-google-client.php';
            }

            foreach ( $files_to_include as $class => $file ) {
                require_once $path . $file;
            }
        }

        $options = Yoast_GA_Options::instance()->options;
        $ga_id = isset( $options['analytics_profile'] ) ? $options['analytics_profile'] : '';

        // this might be the end
        if ( empty( $ga_id ) )
            return;

        $params = array(
            'ids'         => 'ga:'. $ga_id,
            'dimensions'  => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
            'metrics'     => 'ga:pageViews',
            'sort'        => '-ga:pageviews',
            'filters'     => urlencode( 'ga:pagePath=~' . $link_uri . '.*' ),
            'max-results' => 100,
        );

        $response = Yoast_Google_Analytics::get_instance()->do_request( add_query_arg( $params, 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga' ) );

        $pages = isset( $response['response']['code'] ) && 200 == $response['response']['code']
            ? wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response )
            : array();

        $counter = 1;
        $maxpost = 5;
        $post_ids = array();

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            // stop when reaching 5
            if ( $counter > $maxpost )
                break;

            $url = $page['path'];

            // Url is index and we don't want the homepage, skip
            if ( $url == '/' && ! $showhome ) {
                continue;
            }

            // We need to check if there are duplicates
            $default_permalink = strpos( $url, '?p=' );
            $query_var = strpos( $url, '?' );
            $and_var = strpos( $url, '&' );

            // Strip the query var off the url (if not using default permalinks)
            $url = ( false !== $query_var && false === $default_permalink )
                ? substr( $url, 0, $query_var )
                : $url;

            $and_var = strpos( $url, '&' );

            // strip extra args from ?p=id
            if ( $default_permalink && false !== $and_var ) {
                $url = substr( $url, 0, $and_var );
            }

            $post_id = url_to_postid( $url );

            if ( empty( $post_id ) || in_array( $post_id, $post_ids ) )
                continue;

            $post_ids[] = $post_id;
            $counter++;
        }

        set_transient('jr_ga_top_posts', $post_ids, $expires * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    // we can't go any further
    if ( empty( $post_ids ) )
        return;

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
    ) );

    return $query;
}

$top_posts = jr_get_ga_top_posts();

if ( ! empty( $top_posts ) {
    while( $top_posts->have_posts() ) : $top_posts->the_post();
        // loop...
    endwhile;
}
```